# How to Calculate Running Averages

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Scenario:**

I want to calculate the moving average for sales amount for the entire month that has taken place SO FAR.
Each month has a different number of days. If the sales_amount is 0, that means that person has the day off and I need to ignore that value.

**Sample Data:**

```
sales_amount    date         
100            2021-04-01    
200            2021-04-02    
300            2021-04-03    
0              2021-04-04    
100            2021-04-05
```

The Final moving_average value is (100 + 200 + 300 + 100) / (4) since we are ignoring April 4th because it has a 0 sales amount.

**What I have found on this site that doesn't meet my needs:**
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calculate-moving-averages-using-t-sql-in-sql-server but it is for a certain number of days, how can I apply this when each month has a different number of days and I want to ignore certain rows?

**Expected Result:**

```
sales_amount    date         moving_average
100            2021-04-01    100
200            2021-04-02    150
300            2021-04-03    200
0              2021-04-04    200
100            2021-04-05    175
```

**What I have tried doing:**

```
AVG (Sales_Amount) OVER (
Partition BY [Date]
Order by [Date]
,Rows Between Unbounded Preceding and Current Row)
```

Comment: Did you try a basic search of this site? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+running+average

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: FYI "What I have found on this site that doesn't meet my needs:" "sqlservercentral" is not this site :)

Comment: @D-Shih does that help?

Comment: If you create a [mre] with DDL+DML to create the sample data and a complete query its much easier for people to assist.

Comment: I'll have to edit it later then, though I feel like what I am doing is really just a syntax issue?

Comment: Ah, no need for sample data, was able to get what I needed @Dale K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. remove the `PARTITION BY`
2. use `NULLIF()` on `Sales_Amount` since you are not interested in `0`

also you have an extra comma before the `ROWS`

---

```
AVG ( NULLIF(Sales_Amount, 0) ) 
    OVER 
    (
        Order by [Date]
        Rows Between Unbounded Preceding and Current Row
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use 2 aggregate window functions to make it, one for counting your logic another for accumulation `sales_amount`

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(sales_amount) OVER(Order by [Date])/
       SUM(CASE WHEN sales_amount<>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Order by [Date]) moving_average
FROM T
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c4a1618d401b03468fa805d6be370e1)

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error before the `ROWS` and don't need to partition by the date.  But the `ROWS` is not actually needed.  This should do what you want:

```
AVG(NULLIF(Sales_Amount, 0)) OVER (Order by [Date])
```

If you had duplicate dates, then you might want to specify a window frame -- but you would need to explain how the duplicates are handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated queries, such that for all dates of inner query that is less than the outer query are considered for average calculation.

```
SELECT [sales_amount], [date], 
      (SELECT AVG(NULLIF(T2.sales_amount, 0)) 
       FROM your_table T2 
       WHERE T2.orderdate <= T1.orderdate
      ) AS 'moving_average'
FROM your_table T1
ORDER BY T1.date
```

It will consider all the rows that have a [date] less than or equal to current rows [date] and calculate the average for them. As @Squirrel has mentioned, the NULLIF(T2.sales_amount, 0) should skip the 0 values in average calculations.